# Assign DataRowView field to integer variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have created a dataview that bring data from SQL Server and allows me to set the text of textboxes.

```
DataView dv = (DataView)SQLDSRecordPageTest2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

        foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
        {



            TBID.Text = drv["RecordID"].ToString();
            TBRecordTitle.Text = drv["RecordTitle"].ToString();
            TBRecordCreator.Text = drv["Name"].ToString();
```

This works fine for me.

What I am having difficulty with is the assigning int data to a variable so that I can do some logic.

I have tried

```
iRecordOrigin = 1;
iRecordOrigin = drv.GetValue<int>("RecordOriginID");
iRecordOrigin = drv["RecordOriginID"];
```

But either intellisense complains and I know I am doing something wrong or i get a compiler/runtime error.

How do I assign a field from the DataRowView to a variable?

I would like to know this for an:

Integer
String
and
Date

datatypes

I have tried using casting, but have not had any joy.

Regards

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes for any of the types you mentioned.

If your fields in SQL are not being returned as a native SQL type such as `int`, you can use `Convert.ToInt32`

`Convert.ToInt32(drv["RecordOriginID"]);`

You can also change your sql to return correct types such as an `int`, then cast it to an `Int32`

`int i = (int) drv["RecordOriginID"];`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm and easy to understand. I would mark your answer, but I have less that 15 rep as I am a new user. Sam

Answer (score 2):

Convert it.

`int iRecordOrigin = Convert.ToInt32(drv["RecordOriginID"]);`

Comment: Thank you for your additional code to show the left hand side of the assignment. Made it easy to follow and I am sure will help others.I would mark your answer, but I have less that 15 rep as I am a new user. Sam